# Ben 10 comic/activity book

Tags: story-identification, comics, ben-10

I used to own a (small) Ben 10 comic/activity book, it was about 30 to 50 pages and included some simple activities (such as crosswords and word searches) some little fact boxes and several small (non-canon) comics. I remember a few of them, one 10 year old Ben is in a haunted house and turns into Ripjaws to put out a fire, another 15 year old Ben is fighting DNAliens which trap him in a time loop, in another Kevin uses his plumber badge to make a fake Omnitrix and trick DNAliens and in another Ben transforms into Nanomech and goes inside Kevin's car to do... Sometimes... I don't remember what. What strange is that I've found most of the comics but they're in seperate (larger) comic books, without the activities but with other comics that I know weren't in my book.

Comment: It looks like there are a [lot of Ben 10 activity books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ben+10%22+activity+books&tbm=isch).  Do you recognize any of the covers?

Comment: No, unfortunately. However I don't remember any colouring pages in it so you can right those off the list and it didn't have anything Omniverse, only the original series, alien force and ultimate alien. And it had stickers (the only one I remember is an XLR8).

Comment: It could be an "annual"?  They usually contain recycled stories from other comics along with some puzzles and factoids and usually less than 100 pages long for Ben 10 (or at least the one I had was short), but they're usually about A4 portrait (?) size and hard cover, so depends on what you mean by "small". Was it an annual?

Comment: From your description mine sounds like an annual, by small I meant page count but it also wasn't quite A4 size... Maybe A5? I don't remember exactly